# Convergence to electrostatic equilibrium in a conductor

Tags: differential-geometry, classical-electrodynamics, differential-equations

I am interested in proving mathematically that a conductor always converges to equilibrium in the surface. We model it as follows:

We have an ohmic conductor, which means that it is a $3$-manifold $M \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ with boundary such that $J = \sigma E$ in $M$. We are given an initial charge distribution $\rho$ on $M$.

From continuity equation it follows that

$$\nabla \cdot J + \frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t} = 0$$ and so combining Gauss Law and ohms law we have that:

$$\frac{\sigma}{\epsilon} \rho + \frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t} = 0$$ and so we see that $\rho$ decays to $0$ exponentially **on the interior of $M$.**

But clearly on the boundary $\partial M$ of $M$ it does not. So the question is:

**Question:** How can one show that on the boundary we have that $\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t} \to 0$ as $t \to \infty$ ?